# Sybase ASE SP which handles foreign key constraint violation gracefully

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-ase

I'm trying to code a Sybase ASE (15) stored procedure which deletes a customer. It is possible that the DELETE failes due to a "foreign key constraint violation", in which case the stored procedure should rollback the transaction and return.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spumb_deleteCustomer @customertodelete int AS BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION TRX_UMBDELCUSTOMER

   DELETE CREDITCARDS WHERE CUSTOMERID = @customertodelete
   DELETE CUSTOMER_SELECTION_MAP WHERE CUSTOMERID = @customertodelete
   DELETE CUSTOMERS WHERE ID = @customertodelete
   SELECT @rcnt = @@ROWCOUNT
   IF (@rcnt <> 1) BEGIN
     PRINT 'FAILED TO DELETE CUSTOMER'
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRX_UMBDELCUSTOMER
     RETURN
   END 
   COMMIT TRANSACTION TRX_UMBDELCUSTOMER
END
```

When running this SP in a cursor, execution aborts after the first invalid DELETE. How can I make the cursor continue (or, rather, the SP not raise an error)?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 0):

You should check @@error !=0 to indicate an error rather than look for @@rowcount and handle those errors otherwise the calling client may get unexpected messages returned. If you do check @@rowcount you need to save it immediately to a variable after every delete because each command resets it.

If you're specifically looking to pick up foreign key violation messages you can check @@error for 546 or 547 as these will be returned in @@error when it fails:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABCCECF.htm

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABHJIEC.htm